# spread Bootstrap's buttons to 100% of their containing div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How would you let bootstrap self-spread buttons to 100% width of their parent, without adjusting each of the button's width separately ?

for example if i have 8 buttons, 100% containers width / 8 buttons = 12% width for each button.

i would like to:

1. avoid specifying each button's width (today i got 8 tomorrow i'll
   have 20).
2. adjusting the whole .btn-group's child buttons to the center (if you pay close attention you'll see the buttons inside the container are left-aligned for some reason).

[image: btn-group buttons in container]

```css
.btn-group {
  width: 100%;
}
.btn-group>input.btn {
  width: 12%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container panel panel-default">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="A" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="AB" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="ABC" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="ABCD" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="ABCDE" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="ABCD" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="ABC" />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="AB" />
  </div>

  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <p>the buttons above don't take full width of the container</p>
</div>
```

**Example CSS:**

```
.btn-group {
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-group>input.btn {
  width: 12%;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpzZzX)

Comment: have a look at container-fluid: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid you may want to remove the paddings if you use it

Comment: 2. It is displaced to the left because the width should be 12.5% not 12%

Comment: Are you able / willing to change the HTML structure to acheive this?

Comment: @vanburen how so, you may post a solution

Comment: Does each button need to be the exact same width or all the buttons simply need to occupy the entire width of the container?

Comment: @vanburen the latter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This effect is easiest achieved with flexbox.

```
.btn-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn-group > input.btn {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Depending on your what browers you target you might want to prefix

Comment: flex box is a great solution though it does require IE10 or above. if no better solution suggested i'll mark this as an answer. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

HTML   added `.row` inside grid which will allow you to reach 100%.
no I have added `.col-xs-12` inside `.row` which might not be necessary but i have tried to follow what bootstrap gives ie container > row > column.

additions .. make `.btn-group` to be `.btn-block` too, it spans it 100%.

```
<div class="container panel panel-default">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 no-padding">


     <div class="btn-group btn-block my-btn-group">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="A"/>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="AB"/>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="ABC"/>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="ABCD"/>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="ABCDE"/>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="ABCD"/>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="ABC"/>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-responsive" value="AB"/>
    </div>
  </div>
        </div>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>

  <p>the buttons above don't take full width of the container</p>
</div>
```

CSS :  i have removed padding from 'column' and removed margin from buttons insided button group

```
.btn-group>input.btn {
  width:12.5%;
}

.no-padding {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;  
}

.my-btn-group .btn+.btn {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: worthy solution, but it still requires defining a css width for each button (1), which i'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

If using Flexbox isn't the best option for your use case then you can use a `table` layout. Another advantage is the control you have with regard to responsive behavior since the default `btn-group` doesn't offer much in this regard.

> These elements behave like `<table`> HTML elements. It defines a
>   block-level box.

**Basic Example:** *Run with FullPage*

```css
/*Basic Rules*/

.panel-btn {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.panel-btn div {
  display: table-cell;
}
.panel-btn div .btn {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}
/*Rounded Corner Rules*/

.panel-btn div:first-of-type .btn {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
.panel-btn div:last-of-type .btn {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">

  <h2>11 Buttons</h2>

  <div class="panel panel-default panel-btn">
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="A" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="AB" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="ABC" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="ABCD" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="ABCDEF" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="ABCDEFG" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="ABCDEFGH" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="ABCDEFGHI" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="12" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="123" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Responsive Example:** *Run with FullPage and reduce the browser window*

```css
/*Basic Rules*/

.panel-btn {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.panel-btn div {
  display: table-cell;
}
.panel-btn div .btn {
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
}
/*Rounded Corner Rules*/

.panel-btn div:first-of-type .btn {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
.panel-btn div:last-of-type .btn {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
/*Responsive CSS*/

@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  .panel-btn div {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .panel-btn div:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
  }
  .panel-btn div:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
  }
  .panel-btn div:last-child:not(:nth-child(even)) {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
  /*Rounded Corner Rules*/
  .panel-btn div:first-of-type .btn {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  }
  .panel-btn div:nth-child(2) .btn {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  }
  .panel-btn div:last-of-type .btn {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  }
  .panel-btn div:last-child:not(:nth-child(even)) .btn {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  }
  .panel-btn div:nth-last-child(2):not(:nth-child(even)) .btn {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">

  <h2>11 Buttons</h2>

  <div class="panel panel-default panel-btn">
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="A" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="AB" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="ABC" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="ABCD" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="ABCDEF" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="ABCDEFG" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="ABCDEFGH" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="ABCDEFGHI" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="12" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="123" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <br/>

  <h2>10 Buttons</h2>

  <div class="panel panel-default panel-btn">
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="123456789" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="12345678" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="1234567" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="123456" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="12345" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="1234" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="123" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="12" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="A" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <br/>

  <h2>9 Buttons</h2>

  <div class="panel panel-default panel-btn">
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="A" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="AB" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="ABC" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="ABCD" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="ABCDEF" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="ABCDEFG" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="ABCDEFGH" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="ABCDEFGHI" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="1" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <br/>

  <h2>20 Buttons</h2>

  <div class="panel panel-default panel-btn">
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="2" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="3" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="4" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="5" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="6" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="7" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="8" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="9" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="10" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="11" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="12" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="13" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="14" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="15" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="16" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="17" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="18" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="19" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="20" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```